# Psycopg2 not fetching all data that exists in database

Tags: python, database, psycopg2, psql

I'm querying a database using psycopg2, and executing my query within a loop.

```
for i in range(0,len(time)):
            cur2.execute("SELECT  * from obs where ujd=%s;",(time[i],))
            m=cur2.fetchall()
            print time[i], m
```

For some of the queries the data are returned as I would expect. However, sometimes nothing is returned, even though I can successfully query from outside of psycopg2 and get data.

For example, when my loop reaches time[i] of 2456146.72784 psycopg2 returns an empty array: []

If I execute this outside of the loop and manually put in the 2456146.72784 then I get all the data I want.

How can I successfully query from inside a loop?

Comment: What is the datatype for the column `ujd` and the variable `time[i]`?

Comment: ... and in particular, are either/both floating point?

Comment: Thank you for your prompts, simply by stating `float(time[i])`fixes the problem.

Comment: Instead of `cur2.fetchall()`, you can step through the cursor `for i in cur2` or convert it to a list `list(cur2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the data type fixes the problem. In this case they are floats.

Change the line:

```
cur2.execute("SELECT  * from obs where ujd=%s;",(time[i],))
```

to:

```
cur2.execute("SELECT  * from obs where ujd=%s;",(float(time[j]),))
```